# remove duplicate row based only of previous row

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to remove duplicate rows from a data frame, based only on the previous row.  The `duplicate` and `unique` functions will remove all duplicates, leaving you only with unique rows, which is not what I want.

I've illustrated the problem here with a loop.  I need to vectorize this because my actual data set is much to large to use a loop on.

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4)
y <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4)
z <- c(1,2,1,1,3,2,2,4)
xy <- data.frame(x,y,z)

xy
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 2
3 1 1 1
4 1 1 1 #this should be removed
5 3 3 3
6 3 3 2
7 3 3 2 #this should be removed
8 4 4 4

# loop that produces desired output
toRemove <- NULL
for (i in 2:nrow(xy)){
   test <- as.vector(xy[i,] == xy[i-1,])
   if (!(FALSE %in% test)){ 
      toRemove <- c(toRemove, i) #build a vector of rows to remove
   }
}
xy[-toRemove,] #exclude rows
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 2
3 1 1 1
5 3 3 3
6 3 3 2
8 4 4 4
```

I've tried using dplyr's `lag` function, but it only works on single columns, when I try to run it over all 3 columns it doesn't work.

`ifelse(xy[,1:3] == lag(xy[,1:3],1), NA, xy[,1:3])`

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: zx8754's approach is definitely the way to go.  However, I wanted to mention that you can do this with `dplyr::lag` so long as you use `mutate_each`.  For example, `xy %>%
  mutate_each(funs(oneL = . - lag(.))) %>%
  mutate(dup = rowSums(select(. ,contains("oneL"))))%>%
  filter(dup != 0 | is.na(dup)) %>%
  select(x,y,z)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like we want to remove if the row is same as above:

```
# make an index, if cols not same as above
ix <- c(TRUE, rowSums(tail(xy, -1) == head(xy, -1)) != ncol(xy))

# filter
xy[ix, ]
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain the syntax, specfically the `!= ncol(xy)` part (I see it somehow converts the data frame of equality tests into a vector, but I can't figure out how it works) ?  I was expecting rowSums to remove rows with same sum (which could allow for different numbers that sum to same value).  But I tested a few cases where this is true and this method did not remove those rows.

Comment: I am creating 'keep' list, anything with TRUE. First value starting with TRUE, keep the first. Then check rowsums for each row compared to previous, If not same as ncol (in this case 3) then keep, ie keep the rows that are **not** same as above. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you just iterate the list while keeping track of the previous row to compare it to the next row?

If this is true at some point: remember that row position and remove it from the list then start iterating from the beginning of the list.
Don't delete row while iterating because you will get concurrent modification error.

Comment: welcome to SO!  The approach you outline is very inefficient as compared to zx8754 approach.  `R` is a high-level language, so for loops should be avoided.  Especially since subsetting, which utilizes BLAS, is super fast.  Also, it would be helpful to the OP if you provided code.